# Can't get the value of input texts which are dynamically created by ajax and php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to post the values that I get from a form with an Ajax function. First of all, I use another Ajax function to set the text box of from. After that to submit form data, I am trying to use an Ajax function. Here are my functions;

```
<script>
$(function() {

var name1 = $( "#fname" ),
email = $( "#email" ),
password = $( "#password" );

$( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({

autoOpen: false,
height: 500,
width: 550,
modal: true,
buttons: {
"Create an account": function() {
  var bValid = true;

  if ( bValid ) {

    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "reg_arz_ajax.php",
        data: "datastring="+name1.val(),

        success: function(response){
            alert("success");
        },
        error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
            //On error, we alert user
            alert("errrorrrrrrrr");
        }
    });
  }
},
Cancel: function() {
  $( this ).dialog( "close" );
}
},
close: function() {
allFields.val( "" ).removeClass( "ui-state-error" );
}
});

$(".arzyabi").click(function(){

var book_arzyabi = $(this).data("arz");
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "reg_arz_ajax2.php",
    data: "book="+book_arzyabi,
    dataType : "html",
    success: function(response){

        $('#resp').html(response);
    },
    error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
        //On error, we alert user
        alert(thrownError);
    }
});

$( "#dialog-form" ).dialog( "open");

});
 });

</script>
```

HTML

```
<html>
    <body>

        <div id="dialog-form" title="Create new user">
            <p class="validateTips">All form fields are required.</p>

           <form>
               <fieldset>
                   <label for="name">Name</label>
                   <div id="resp" ></div>
                   <label for="email">Email</label>
                   <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
                   <label for="password">Password</label>
                   <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
               </fieldset>
           </form>
        </div>
      <button id="bot" class="arzyabi" style="font-family:Tahoma;" data-arz="test">enter</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

in reg_arz_ajax2.php:

```
echo '<input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" value="ajax val" >';
```

Comment: This might be helpful: https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Comment: The problem is that there is no element `#fname`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've mistead

```
<input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
```

from your HTMl so what doesn't exists could not be sent..., check my jsFindle: http://jsfiddle.net/6X7Bm/6/

Best regards!

Comment: Sending data as an object instead of a querystring doesn't make a difference. This will not solve the problem.

Comment: in HTML you have posted I can't see the input: $( "#fname" )

Comment: In the jsFindel I've craeted in console you can see that the javascript variables are sent thru POST method: http://jsfiddle.net/6X7Bm/6/. Best regards!

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. Other SO users who may be able ti help may skip this question because it shows as having an answer, but it doesn't fix the problem. All you've done is replace a querystring with an object which makes no difference at all. You should remove this answer for the sake of the person asking the question.

Comment: fname element generated with ajax in php file.

Comment: then try a global var outside the $(function){} and when the first ajax is finished add that value there, if you construct $("#fname") after document load ready sure the javascript var : var name1 = $( "#fname" ) will be undefined

Comment: or better don't store the value : var name1 = $( "#fname" ), but put: data: "datastring="+$( "#fname" ).val(),

Comment: thanks for your help. last comment resolved my problem.

Comment: can I have a check please?

Comment: so Nigel finaly it does answer the question so you should reconsider your downvote.